# Land snail motionless and not retracting after eating rotten rice

Tags: diet, snails

I found a land snail on an orange, and since it was cold outside, I decided to keep it. I put some soil and some water in a jar and left it inside the jar. I tried to feed it with vegetables, tomato and potato, but it was not interested. But rice worked. It came out of its shell at nights and ate rice.

Today it ate a rotten grain of rice and its behavior changed immediately. It remained motionless until I dripped water on it. Then it climbed the jar and unlike ever before it didn't retract.

It used to retract and seal its shell opening, but now it's been still on the jar wall. Maybe it's natural that it doesn't seal now because it ate some water today for the first time.

Is this behavior natural? If not, how can I help it?

Update: it started moving around after a few hours and eats a lot but still outside its shell. So, I keep it wet by spraying water. I have to update the question into "is it normal that it doesn't retract? And should I worry about it getting dry?"

Answer (score 2):

If you decide to keep any animal as a pet, you need to be sure you've [done your research and fully understand the animal's needs](https://www.rspca.org.uk/documents/1494939/7712578/Giant+African+land+snails) before committing to care for it. First step is to always extensively research your animal.

You shouldn't have fed it rice, especially rotten rice. Since you can't undo this, you need to keep an eye on it over the next few days. Some things to watch for:

- Deep retraction (beyond sealing the shell) is a bad sign. It seems good that he's still out and about and moving.
- Inactivity is a sign of incorrect temperature or humidity.
- If he's moving, climbing, or looking like he's trying to get away/get out, you need to address how you're caring for your snail.

[This site addresses many snail issues very thoroughly](https://www.petsnails.co.uk/problems/index.html).

But, I think there are a few things you *can and should* do in the mean time:

**Habitat**: You should first address your [snail's enclosure](https://www.myhappysnails.com/how-to-keep-pet-snails). A jar is likely not large enough for a land snail (unless your land snail is very small). I would recommend getting a plastic or glass terrarium. (Make sure the lid seals well, but that there's lots of ventilation.) Snails are also very sensitive to humidity and temperature, so be sure you know the right levels for your type of snail. You may need to invest in a heat pad. The terrarium will also need to be cleaned regularly.

**Food**: Snails are [omnivorous and will eat many things](https://www.atshq.org/what-do-snails-eat/), but you do have to be careful. When feeding the snail, always wash anything you give it to remove any trace of pesticides or other harmful things. Remove any uneaten food within a day, so it doesn't rot or mold. Snails can eat most leafy greens, most vegetables, and many fruits. They can't eat anything with salt, citrus (was he eating the orange you found him on?), or starchy foods (including rice). Never let the food go bad!

**Calcium**: [Calcium is extremely important](https://www.petsnails.co.uk/care/feeding.html) to a snail's diet. It's what keeps  it's shell strong. You can buy calcium supplements to sprinkle on food you provide your snail. A snail needs a constant supply of calcium.

Good luck with your snail! I hope the issues are addressed and you're able to provide him a safe and comfortable habitat.

Comment: Thanks for the useful link and information. I could identify the snail; it's probably Cepaea Nemoralis. I also found its diet on a detailed article at animaldiversity.org which consists of insects, leaves, wood, fruit and flowers.